# How to show user session info in another page - HTML5 Hybrid App

Tags: php, ajax, html, session, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a login page (login.html) that request to my server when logging in. As the user logged-in, the server (PHP) respond to login credential of the user then create a session.

```
$user_fullname = $_SESSION['user_fullname'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
```

After a successful login it will redirect to the homepage (home.html)

How can I show the user details on homepage? Do I need to create another ajax request (in homepage) to the server then `echo json_encode` the user detail?

Comment: create homepage in php and use session variables.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar I am developing a Hybrid App. Do I really need to create a homepage in php?